# Is there any way to show TabBarItem image default as selected?

Tags: iphone, uitabbaritem

In my application After login successful my schedule screen opens. It has below 3 TabbarItems with My Schedule option itself. When i come to this screen My schedule items image should be highlighted and other 2 r as normal. How I can achieved this? 
   Plz help me soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the `selectedIndex` property of `UITabBarController`

```
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can do this. I am new in iPhone. -python

Comment: Post some code as to how you are initializing the tab bar controller.

Comment: I drag and drop UITabbar and UITabBarItems in viewbased application. When login get successful Myschedule screen comes. Below it has 3 tabbaritems one of these is myschedule. I want that highlighted when this screen comes. Now all 3 r unhighlighted. Is there any option to make one highlighted n other 2 unhighlited?

Answer (score 0):

@python

You use this code I think this will help for you and it also highlighted your tab bat item which you are selected.

```
UITabBarController *tabbar1 = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];


onecontroller  *second = [[onecontroller alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
second.title=@"Leaderboard";

secondcontroller *third=[[secondcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
third.title=@"Scorecards";

thirdcontroller *one=[[thirdcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 one.title=@"Compete";

tabbar1.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:one, second,third,nil]; 
tabbar1.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
[self.view addSubview:tabbar1.view];
```

and add this line in your viewdidload which view you first highleted

tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

or also add on above also but then its alwayes highlited if u want changeable then every viewcontroller view did load you write this code with chage index value.